# HTTP SSL VPN Client? (alternative to Cisco's AnyConnect VPN)

Tags: windows, cisco-vpn-client, ssl-vpn

Is there any free HTTP SSL VPN clients around, one that can act as an alternative to Cisco's own HTTP SSL VPN client (called AnyConnect)?

---

The Cisco [AnyConnect client has acknowledged problems, with no forthcoming solutions](https://serverfault.com/questions/307602/cisco-anyconnect-ssl-vpn-client-allows-local-lan-access-but-not-on-additional-m). Which is why I'm hoping for an alternative.

---

**Note:** I'm only talking about the HTTP SSL VPN Client, not the HTTP SSL VPN Server. (If it were up to me they wouldn't be using Cisco at all, but it's not up to me.)

**Note:** [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) is a client that talks to their servers once you sign up for their service. It's not a generic VPN client.

**Note:** [ShrewSoft VPN](http://www.shrew.net/) is a client that uses IPsec and pre-shared keys, and was a good replacement for Cisco's **old** client - but not the new AnyConnect **SSL** VPN client.

**Note:** Windows 7's VPN client fails to negotiate when presented with an SSL VPN connection.

**Note:** I am looking for Windows clients only.

Comment: Paul's VPN Law: Each release of a VPN client will work successfully in a narrower set of use cases than the previous version

Comment: Well, in case anybody wonders: There's really no such thing as a "universal VPN client". This is especially true for proprietary VPN servers/extensions.

Comment: Your note about OpenVPN is incorrect. OpenVPN is a generic VPN solution, which you can install on your own server and use OpenVPN clients to connect to it. See http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html

Answer (score 14):

The Windows port of OpenConnect is now working, and there's even a GUI tool for it. See https://github.com/openconnect/openconnect-gui/wiki

Answer (score 2):

While there isn't a port "yet", the authors of [OpenConnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/platforms.html) seem to think it would be straightforward.

There is discussion of a port [here](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/openconnect-devel/2011-February/000284.html).

Perhaps it would be worth investing the time to get it working given Cisco's response.

Answer (score 2):

[Shimo](https://www.shimovpn.com/) (Mac only) seems to support Cisco AnyConnect among the others